# How to clear char array using pointer?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, character

I have a character pointer which points to the character array.
I want to clear the character array and then string copy some other array in it.The memset doesn't work on char pointer.
Is there some other way around to do that ?

```
int main(){

        char a[100] = "coepismycollege";
        char *p;
        p  = a;
        test(p);
        printf("After function : %s", a);
}
void test(char *text){
        char res[120] = "stackisjustgreat";
        printf("text = %s\nres =  %s\n", text , res);
        memset(&text, 0 , sizeof(*text));
        strcpy(text, res);
}
```

output should be : stackisjustgreat

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `memset(&text, 0 , sizeof(*text));`--> `memset(text, 0 , strlen(text));` But in this case `memset` is not necessary.

Comment: doesn't help either !

Comment: @Savan BLUEPIXY's comment is correct. If it didn't work for you, then you need to post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), because your code doesn't compile. To get more information about what's wrong with your code, compile with `-Wall` on gcc or clang.

Comment: You were right @BLUEPIXY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sizeof(*text)` will always be 1 (it is same as to `sizeof(char)`). It is, however, sufficient, if you intended to null only the first byte of string.

`memset`'s first argument is pointer to start of memory block, and `text` is already a pointer, so `memset(text, 0 , strlen(text));` is correct (without the `&`)

However, `memset` is pointless, as the following strcopy will overwrite it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can change `test()` function like this:

```
void test(char* text) {
    char res[120] = "stackisjustgreat";
    const size_t len = strlen(res); // NOT sizeof(res)
    memset(text, 0, len); // This is actually not necesary!
    strncpy(text, res, len); // text will already be properly null-terminated
}
```

Even shorter version could be:

```
void test(char* test) {
    char res[120] = "stackisjustgreat";
    strcpy(test, res, strlen(res));
}
```

Just find out the length of the string to which `res` points by `strlen(res)` and then use `str(n)cpy()` to copy the string. Because `str(n)cpy()` copy the null character as well, there is no more necessary to be done.

Comment: Your first snippet will actually cause undefined behavior. original pointer `a` points to char[100], and you are setting 120 bytes of it to 0.

Comment: @TomášZahradníček No, because I am using `strlen(res)`, which actually goes through the `res` string byte after byte and stops when first null byte occurs, which is right after the `"stackisjustgreat` string (17th byte will be NULL, if I count correctly). The problem you point out would appear if I used `sizeof(res)` instead of `strlen(res)`.

Comment: I stand corrected, didn't realise you used `strlen` that treats argument as null terminated string

Answer (score 0):

On the line with the memset, argument 1 should simply be text, text is already a pointer. Putting &text will put a pointer to that pointer.